# Amazon Kendra: AccessDeniedException with Cognito role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I've been trying to get Amazon Kendra to work using the Java SDK from our website and this error is haunting me.

**Background**:
Kendra indexes have been created and a connector to an S3 bucket is in place.

If I use the search function in Kendra within the console, valid data is returned and everything works as it should.

**Now on to our website**:
Using the Java SDK with a cognito identity pool to make calls to Kendra, we receive the following error:

> **Error**
>
> AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::*accountnumber*:assumed-role/Cognito_botpoolUnauth_Role/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: kendra:Query on resource: arn:aws:kendra:eu-west-1:*accountnumber*/kendra-test-index

Please note that we have a policy allowing full access in place attached to the `Cognito_botpoolUnauth_Role`.

It's baffling me as I've checked repeatedly with no success.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

**Update**

Ok I'm back

I've checked the SCP's. Theres no SCP's prohibiting the use of Kendra.

I have looked at the trust relationship as well and it seems good too:

{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Effect": "Allow",
"Principal": {
"Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
},
"Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
"Condition": {
"StringEquals": {
"cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "eu-west-1:532e0bcd-fc6e-4192-a3ef-37f2ae188820"
},
"ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
"cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "unauthenticated"
}
}
}
]
}

Answer (score 1):

> If I use the search function in Kendra within the console , valid data is returned and everything works as it should.

The error is not about your permissions in console to query Kendra

The **error is about a role** called `Cognito_botpoolUnauth_Role` which does not have such permissions.

You would have to got to IAM console, find the role in question, and **verify if needed permissions to access Kendra** are there. You can add them as inline policies if needed to the role.

However, even if your role has needed permissions, it **still may be denied access** to the resource. For example, there could be AWS Organization's SCP prohibiting that. Also, there could be a resource-based policies on Kendra that denies such access. Other possibility could be access to KMS if Kendra requires that.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin 

I have edited the original post. I am at a roadblock as I am not sure what else it could be

Comment: Have you found it out eventually? I'm spinning my wheels on the same thing.